# Which is the name of the pre home screens?

Tags: terminology

I am in doubt, which is name of all the pre home screens?

- Login / Signup
- Language Selection Screen
- Forgot password
- Privacy and T&C
- Secondary flows out of the core platform
- Even sometimes, the onboarding.

Comment: Are the items you mentioned shown to the user in linear sequence? What digital medium are you targeting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### These pages (often named utility pages) are referred to as [utility navigation areas](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/utility-navigation/).

From Nielsen Norman Group:

> Tools that websites provide vary with their size and mission, but many utility-navigation areas include:

- Contact us
- Follow us
- Locale switcher / language tools
- Log in / Sign up
- Print Save Share Subscribe
- Tools for changing font size

> Utility navigation consists of secondary actions and tools, such as contact, subscribe, save, sign in, share, change view, print. These activities strongly affect website visitor satisfaction, user experience, and engagement. Put utilities where people expect and need them.

I'm not sure about onboarding, but the article referenced above goes in depth about designing utility navigation, if that helps as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the very first screen the user sees while the app is loading, that screen is called:

**Splash Screen**, or also **Launch Screen**.

You can find more information and guidelines here:

**Apple:** https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen/
**Google:** https://material.io/design/communication/launch-screen.html#usage

Answer (score 0):

These screens belong to a few different categories. Also they aren't necessarily pre home screen.

**authentication and security**

- Login / Signup
- Forgot password

**localisation**

- Language Selection Screen

**legal and fine print**

- Privacy and T&C